# Floating Point Error

Tags: java, c++, floating-point, cout

I have a strange error in my C++ Code:

```
float cosTheta = someFunction();
cout << cosTheta << endl;  // prints 1 on the console
if (cosTheta == 1) {       // doesn't enter this condition
    cout << "it is 1" << endl;
}
float sinTheta = sqrt(1 - pow(cosTheta, 2));
return (someVariable * sinTheta);
```

The problem is: cosTheta is 1, but it does not enter the condition, although it prints 1 on the screen. When I print the returned Value, it should be 0, because cosTheta is 1, so sinTheta gets 0 and the return value gets 0, but I get 0.0953562...

I tested the same code in Java and there I get 0 as a result.

Comment: Did you try searching for anything before you posted this question? Did you enter your title "floating point error" into Google? [Do you know what floating point error is?](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: Are you sure that `cosTheta` really is exactly 1 and not, say, 0.9999999 that's just getting *rounded* to 1 for display?

Comment: I am not sure, that it isn't exactly 1, it could be 0.99... What frustrates me is, that in Java I get exactly 1...

Comment: You might want to write `pow(cosTheta, 2)` as `cosTheta * cosTheta`. It is better for a variety of reasons and yet your compiler may not automatically compile one as the other. This is not related to your perceived problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't compare floating point numbers with `==`. Rounding errors in floating-point operations mean that you should choose a precision `EPSILON` (adequated to your case) and use it like this:

```
const float EPSILON = 0.00001;

if( fabs(cosTheta - 1) < EPSILON ) {
    cout << "It is approximately 1\n";
}
```

Comment: I understand that, but why do I get exactly 1 in Java, so that sinTheta there gets 0.

Comment: It's possible your Java implementation is using a larger (more precise) floating point variable OR your Java implementation of `someFunction` is leaking less precision for some reason...

Comment: Yes, in Java I use double. But why does higher precision help here?

Comment: We can't know that unless you tell what is the secret sauce of `someFunction()`... In short: **every operation** in floating point leaks some precision. If you do `0.000383 + 0.292` the result may or may not be within `0.001` of `0.292383`, depending on which precision you use. And floating-point errors are cumulative, so for each floating-point-operation done inside `someFunction()`, the overall precision of it will go down... try you C++'s `double`s and tell what is the result!

Comment: So if I change both to double, then it should have the same results?

Comment: I won't give any guarantees, but it would be better (`float` has only six digits of precision or so)

Comment: @user2500558 - The bottom line is this: don't compare floating point values for equality.  Even in Java, don't do it.  For any language that uses binary to approximate real numbers, don't do it.  This is not a language issue, but a computer science one.  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/floating-point-arith.html.